# (Spark - Scala) error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

I'm doing a Link Analysis project on Retail Industry using Spark Mllib. My schema is:

ID - Long Chain - Int Dept - int Category - Int Company - Long Brand - Long Date - Date ProductSize - Int ProductMeasure - Chararray PurchaseQuantity - Int PurchaseAmount - Double

And the code that I'm using is:

```
spark-shell
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators

case class Transactions(ID:Long,Chain:String,Dept:String,Category:String,Company:String,Brand:String,Date:String,ProductSize:String,ProductMeasure:String,PurchaseQuantity:String,PurchaseAmount:String)

def parseTransactions(str:String): Transactions = {
     val line = str.split(",")
     Transactions(line(0).toLong,line(1),line(2),line(3),line(4),line(5),line(6),line(7),line(8),line(9),line(10))
     }

val textRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/transactions.csv")     

val transactionsRDD = textRDD.map(parseTransactions).cache()

val products = transactionsRDD.map(Transactions => (Transactions.ID,Transactions.Chain,Transactions.Dept,Transactions.Category,Transactions.Company,Transactions.Brand)).distinct

products.take(1)

val productMap = products.map { case ((ID), name) => (ID -> name) }.collect.toList.toMap
```

I'm getting the folloiwng error:

```
<console>:46: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: (Long, String, String, String, String, String)
         val productMap = products.map { case ((ID), name) => (ID -> name) }.collect.toList.toMap
                                              ^
<console>:46: error: not found: value ID
         val productMap = products.map { case ((ID), name) => (ID -> name) }.collect.toList.toMap
                                                               ^
<console>:46: error: value toList is not a member of Array[Nothing]
         val productMap = products.map { case ((ID), name) => (ID -> name) }.collect.toList.toMap
                                                                                     ^
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this produces a collection of tuples of type (Long, String, String, String, String, String)
val products = transactionsRDD.map(Transactions => (Transactions.ID,Transactions.Chain,Transactions.Dept,Transactions.Category,Transactions.Company,Transactions.Brand)).distinct

// since products is a collection of sextuples, the pattern match should match the tuple length
val productMap = products.map { case (ID, chain, dept, cat, comp, brand) => (ID -> chain) }.collect.toList.toMap
```

Comment: var dist_company_model_vals_df  =  company_model_vals_df.select("model_id","fiscal_quarter","fiscal_year").distinct()

Comment: '''
 dist_company_model_vals_df.map{ case (model_id,fiscal_quarter,fiscal_year)  =>{
    var inputDf = company_model_vals_df.select("*").where( col("model_id").===(model_id)
                                                                .and(col("fiscal_quarter").===(fiscal_quarter))
                                                                .and(col("fiscal_year").===(fiscal_year))
                                                                   )                                                     
          }
        } 

'''

Comment: Getter error " constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2, T3) required: org.apache.spark.sql.Row "" Any clue how to fix this issue??